# Base64 decode resultado en caracter no adecudo con Java

Tags: java, base64, certificado

Buen día, necesito decodificar un texto base64 que contiene un certificado p12, al utilizar código java no regresa el contenido apropiado sin embargo utilizando una página online si lo hace, expongo los detalles:

Texto en base64 Original:

> MII2zwIBAzCCNpUGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCNoYEgjaCMII2fjCCDPcGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCDOgEggzkMIIM4DCCBm8GCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIE7jCCBOowHAYKKoZI

Java Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
public class DecodeString64 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {

        String str = "MII2zwIBAzCCNpUGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCNoYEgjaCMII2fjCCDPcGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCDOgEggzkMIIM4DCCBm8GCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIE7jCCBOowHAYKKoZI";

        // Decode data 
        
        String decoded = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(str),  StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        System.out.println("decoded value is \t" + decoded);

}
```

A) Resultado de ejecución:

> ???0??0
> *?H

B) Resultado utilizando la página https://www.base64decode.org/ (se utiliza la opción archivo)

> 0‚6Ï0‚6•  *†H†÷  ‚6†‚6‚0‚6~0‚÷    *†H†÷  ‚è‚ä0‚à0‚o*†H†÷
>
> ‚î0‚ê0
> *†H

El resultado B es el correcto pues lo interpreto utilizando la siguiente instrucción:

```
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); 
    FileInputStream fis =
        new FileInputStream("miarchivodecodificado"); 

    ks.load(fis, "password".toCharArray());  
    fis.close();
```

Agradezco la ayuda que puedan brindarme para solventar este inconveniente.

---

Envió un mayor fragmento de la cadena:
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

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esta linea, devuelve lo mismo que la pagina de base 64 decoder.
Adjunto código de ejemplo

```
import java.util.Base64;
String str = "MII2zwIBAzCCNpUGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCNoYEgjaCMII2fjCCDPcGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCDOgEggzkMIIM4DCCBm8GCyqGSIb3DQEMCgECoIIE7jCCBOowHAYKKoZI";
byte[] bytesDecodificados = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
String cadenaDecodificada = new String(bytesDecodificados);
System.out.println("decodificado: " + cadenaDecodificada);
```

Código completo: https://paiza.io/projects/BwXy30reJHH5hsf9j4hnZg

Comment: Estimado Eduardo agradezco tu ayuda, ejecuté el código indicado levantando todo el archivo que necesito decodificar y me generó el siguiente error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3f
 at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
 at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
 at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
 at firmabase64.Main.main(Main.java:29)
C:\Users\Kleber\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)